# jquery display inline-block then fade

Tags: jquery, fadeout

I have the following jQuery:

```
$('#register_email_address').siblings('.error').css('display','inline-block');
```

I would like the above to fadeOut after so many seconds.

I have tried the following:

```
$('#register_email_address').siblings('.error').css('display','inline-block').fadeOut(3000);
```

But this doesnt seem to work?

Any ideas?

Cheers,
Dan

The above code if for form validation. onBlur of any input field the above is initiated, the show the class .error. is then shown. This then displays, and stays displayed.

the .error class contains another classs of .showerror. This is the class i would actually like to fadeOut after so long.

Comment: You will need to use setTimeout() for this.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: The HTML might be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your current code doesn't work is that the 3000 value you're using is being applied to the fadeOut (ie: the fade out animation is taking 3000 milliseconds).

There are a couple of options here, but personally I would use jQuery's [.delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/), which is specifically used to cause a pause in processing a chain .  Dropping this into your chain should - in theory - do exactly what you're after.

For example, this will cause a 3000 pause between setting the CSS, and fading the element back out:

```
$('#register_email_address').siblings('.error').css('display','inline-block').delay(3000).fadeOut();
```

Comment: i have tried the above and it doesn't seem to be working? i have also tried setTimeout which also doesn't work

Comment: @danyo in that case I suspect you've some other issue.  Best bet would be to update this question with more details: a preview link if you can, or a code excerpt that we can see otherwise.  It may well be that you've another issue influencing this (like potential validation issues for example, or jQuery not loading, etc).

Comment: jQuery if working as other elements are fine. I will update now with more details.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$('#register_email_address').siblings('.error').css('display','inline-block').delay(3000).fadeOut();
```